# Buildroot 2020.02 why can't I add resize2fs binaries?

Tags: buildroot

I'm building a lightweight distribution for the Raspberry Pi (dedicated to mpd player).
As I'd like to add an filesystem extender (like raspbian) I need resize2fs to be build.

But even if in menuconfig I select target -> FS tools-> e2fsprogs -> resize2fs, this binary is not built.
Can't figure why!
Have you got any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enable resize2fs after having already built e2fsprogs, then you need to reconfigure e2fsprogs:

1. `make menuconfig`, enable `resize2fs`
2. `make e2fsprogs-dirclean`
3. `make`

This is because resize2fs is not a Buildroot *package*, it is an optional component of the e2fsprogs package. And since Buildroot does not track changes to the package configuration, it does not know it has to rebuild the package in this case.

To better understand, read the Buildroot manual section [8.3. Understanding how to rebuild packages](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rebuild-pkg). Section  [8.2. Understanding when a full rebuild is necessary](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#full-rebuild) would is very useful too.